# What is the EXPORT privilege on ORACLE

Tags: database, oracle, export, database-schema, sql-grant

I have created a user say A. I want to export some of my schemas using A user.

For example, I have B and C users. I want to export B schemas using A user. Which grant do I have to use?

I am using this statement:

```
EXP FILE = B.DMP OWNER(B)
```

But it is not working. A user has only select grant on B schemas. There is no other grant A has.

Which grant do I have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export the schema of another user, you'll need the role `DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE`. Normally only DBAs have this role, as it gives access to all data in the database.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL200

Besides, use `expdp` instead of `exp`...

Comment: I tried this --> EXPDP FILE = TEST.DMP OWNER(B) and it tells me I has completed and put the file to C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ADMIN\SETUP\DPDUMP\TEST.DMP but unfortunately there is no such a path?

Comment: Should I specify  a path address, if so how?

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, have a look at the section "Default Locations for Dump, Log, and SQL Files" in the cited documentation.